# typescript jest unit tests fails on compilation of default value on private property (but passes locally)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babel-jest

All my Typescript unit tests run fine using Jest locally, but one fails on the CI server.

It fails when trying to import a TSX file on the `colors` property.

```
export class Product {
   private name: string;
   private colors: string[] = [];
}
```

with this error

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
...

   colors = [];
          ^ 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Strangely the test compiles and runs fine, if I initialise the property value in the constructor, rather than as a Default Value, like so...

```
export class Product {
   private colors: string[];
   constructor(){
      this.colors = p[];
   }
}
```

Possible issues?

- Is this possibly a Typescript version issue?
- Is it possibly not transpiling this file at all?

I'm using `babel-jest` configured via the `transform` section in my `jest.config.js`

Comment: It might be related to the node version. It looks like to be working from node v12 so might have to require your CI from that version

Comment: I'm running node v12 locally and v10 on the server. How would that make a difference? Thanks :)

Comment: Ref to this https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--instance-class-fields which tells class fields from v12

Comment: Spot on! Can you add it as an answer pls :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you put `"engines": { "node": ">=12.0.0" }` in your package json if the CI can help you select the right version :)

Comment: Did you try with ts-jest ?